# Bubble sort read from file generates random numbers

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int bubble(int arr[], int siz)
{
    int i;
    int sortat;
    do
    {
        sortat = 1;
        for (i = 0; i <= siz-1; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i+1])
            {
                int aux = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = aux;
                sortat = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    while(sortat == 0);
    for (i = 1; i <= siz; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a[1000];
    int i;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("rand1k.txt");
    if(fin.is_open())
    {
        for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
            fin>>a[i];
    }
    bubble(a,1000);
}
```

I believe the problem lies with readin from the text file, as the sort worked really well before I added that.
Note:the text files are not in the same folder as the project, but in a subfolder.

Comment: What could you do to check that hypothesis?

Comment: Remove the read from file thingie, and hard code an array to get sorted. But why would I test something that already has been tested?

Comment: So you _know_ it's from the file reading part. How could you investigate that part?

Comment: I don't know that.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `open` you should be able to figure out how to check for errors. ETA: what if `fin.is_open()` isn't true? What are you sorting?

Comment: Where can I find that? Also, could the problem be the fact that I did not close the file?

Comment: @NAlexP You did close the file, the destructor did that for you.

Comment: @NAlexP Always the most likely reason for these problems is that either a) the file isn't where you think it is or b) the program isn't looking for the file where you think it is.

Comment: *`for (i = 1; i <= siz; i++)`*. C++ uses 0-indexing, not 1-indexing. (so you have out of bound access leading to **U**ndefined **B**ehaviour).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Jarod. I only used that to see if the sort actually works, I started from 0 in the other places. John, does the file have to be in the same folder as the project?

Comment: @NAlexP I've just noticed 'Note:the text files are not in the same folder as the project, but in a subfolder.' that's the problem, add the subfolder to the file name in the program, or move the file.

Comment: Same as working directory (which might be specified in most IDE).

Comment: slightly offtopic, but: you can copy content of file into std::vector using std::copy with 1 line of code, and sort vector with std::sort - another line of code. Doing it this way you practically have no room for mistake/error.

Comment: I think the important question is, what happens if the file isn't open?

Comment: @john can you please answer that so I can give you your internet points?

Comment: @scrappedcola cplusplus.com is often outdated, incomplete, or plain wrong. Give a try to cppreference.com, you won't go back ;)

Comment: @YSC Good to know. The last reference I used for C++ was the Stroustrup book (before web was a thing), so in general my C++ references are dated.

Answer (score 1):

In case that file cannot be opened or reading fails in middle your sorting function access unitialized data and you get undefined behavior. So you can improve your code:

1 Initialize your data - `int a[1000] = {}`;

2 If file is not opened provide error message and exit

```
ifstream fin("rand1k.txt");
if( !fin ) {
    std::cerr << "error: cannot open file" << std::endl;
    return 100; // or whatever error code you prefer
}
```

3 Check that each input is successful:

```
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++) {
        fin>>a[i];
        if( !fin ) {
            std::cerr << "error on reading " << i << " element" << std::endl;
            return 101; // or whatever error code you prefer
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed that I did not provide a path to a file that was not in the same work directory as my project. Thank you guys.